# Getting Repository Public Key in GitHub Actions

Tags: powershell, github, scripting, github-actions, github-api

I am using GitHub Actions to try and manage some of the secrets within one of the environments in the repository where Actions are being triggered (same repo, basically).

I am using the hosted Windows runner, with the following command to try and get the public key for the environment through PowerShell:

```
$keyData = curl -H @{"Accept" = "application/vnd.github.v3+json"; "Authorization" = "token $env:SL_GITHUB_TOKEN"} https://api.github.com/repos/I_PUT_MY_ACCOUNT_HERE/MY_REPOSITORY_HERE_AS_WELL/environments/Production/secrets/public-key | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The `SL_GITHUB_TOKEN` enviroment variable is a Personal Access Token (PAT) with maximum permissions (every checkbox selected when creating through the GitHub UI).

However, when the code is executed *within* the GitHub Actions runner, I get an error:

```
message           : Must have admin rights to Repository.
documentation_url : https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#get-an-environment-public-key
```

This is odd, because I can run the *exact* same command locally on my computer, with the same PAT, and get the correct output (the public key, as expected).

To make sure that the REST API is actually accessible in GitHub Actions runner, within the exact same step I added another command that uses the exact same PAT:

```
$userData = curl -H @{"Accept" = "application/vnd.github.v3+json"; "Authorization" = "token $env:SL_GITHUB_TOKEN"} https://api.github.com/users/MY_USER_NAME_ON_GH | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The correct data was returned, so it seems like something funky is going on with the Secrets API.

What could be the issue here? Is it just the Secrets API that needs special permissions *within* the runner that I am missing? It's clearly not the PAT since the same token can be used locally with no issues.

Comment: This syntax `$env:SL_GITHUB_TOKEN` is not a thing. What exactly are you trying to do? Read a secret? That'd be `${{ secrets.SL_GITHUB_TOKEN }}`.

Comment: @rethab it is a thing in the context that I am building. I've explicitly declared the secret to be assigned to an environment variable.

Comment: If it's an env, then do `${{ env.SL_GITHUB_TOKEN }}`

Comment: Not it, unfortunately @rethab - the environment variable syntax works as expected, the problem is that the API doesn't seem to get the right permissions for some reason when executed from inside the action.